# How to continue playing a youtube video at background when switch from my app back to home screen

Tags: ios, multithreading, youtube-api

Seems the default action for iOS 6 is to stop the video from playing after I switch to HOME screen. Then if I want to listen to the audio I have to go back to the app and press the 'Play' button again. I am using youtube API.

How can I continue playing the video when the application is in `UIApplicationStateInactive` and `UIApplicationStateBackground`. I just want to be able to listen to the audio even if I am on HOME screen or the screen is locked. Should I use a background thread or restart playing the video at the previous position as it was before turning the app inactive?

Comment: Curious - is the goal so you can still hear the audio?

Comment: Yes I want to hear the audio of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the app 'Jasmine'. They managed to do something similar to what you are seeking. However, UIApplicationStateInactive/UIApplicationStateBackground will cause the video to pause. Double tapping the home button and then pressing the audio play button will cause the video's audio to resume without keeping the app active.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I want. I am using an app that can continue playing the video when I go back to the HOME screen. I just wonder how does the developer do that.

Comment: Ahh I see. I don't believe that I have seen an app do that yet. I've only seen audio continue playing while the app becomes inactive. Video seems to shut off every time. The only solution I can think of is creating your own video playback class that doesn't use audio. Sync that video to the audio classes that are allowed to play when the app becomes inactive. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the new iOS 7. You may have some luck there.

> **Inter-App Audio**
>
> Now your apps can make beautiful music together. With Inter-App Audio,
>   apps can register their audio streams to share with other apps. For
>   example, a series of apps could publish audio streams of instrument
>   tracks while another uses the combination of these streams to compose
>   a song. Inter-App Audio also provides for MIDI control of audio
>   rendering, remotely launching other registered Inter-App Audio apps
>   and more.